# Continuity between metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis

I know that this question was asked before, but my professor said "prove using sequences", and I haven't seen a proof which uses sequences; I have no idea how to go about it. I can prove it *without* using sequences, but like I said, I am stuck!

I am not looking for an answer, but a way to get started would be really helpful.

- Let $(\Omega, d)$, $(\Delta, d')$ be metric spaces and $f: \Omega \rightarrow \Delta$, such that for any $E \subset \Omega$, $f(\overline{E}) \subset \overline{f(E)}$. Prove that $f$ is continuous.

This is from the more general question which says "Let $(\Omega, d)$, $(\Delta, d')$ be metric spaces prove that $f$ is continuous iff for any $E \subset \Omega$, $f(\overline{E}) \subset \overline{f(E)}$."

EDIT: After the comments, I have tried the following:

Let $(x_n) \in \Omega$ and $x_n \to x \in \Omega$. We claim $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. Define
$$ E = \{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n, \cdots\}$$ Then, we have the following $$f(\overline{E}) = f(E \cup \{ x\}) =f(E) \cup f(x) \subset \overline{f(E)}$$ So, $f(x) \in \overline{f(E)}$.

Comment: Yes, you have $f(x) \in \overline {f(E)}$. But this is not yet $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. That $f(x) \in \overline {f(E)}$ only imply that a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ of $x_n$ so that $f(x_{n_k})$ to $f(x)$.

Comment: @JohnMa So, what direction should I go in? I keep getting stuck at that fact.

Comment: Please see the edit of my answer.

Comment: @phatty .Which definition of continuity are you starting with? There are many equivalent definitions. $f(\bar E)\subset \overline {f(E)}$  is one of them,but clearly not your definition,as you are asking for a proof of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get started, I would try to let $x_n \in \Omega$ and $x_n \to x \in \Omega$. I want to show $f(x_n) \to f(x)$, so it seems that setting 
$$ E = \{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n, \cdots\}$$
would be a good choice. Note $\overline E = E \cup \{x\}$.

**Edit**: Now you know that for every sequence $x_n \to x$, there is a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ of $\{x_n\}$ so that $f(x_{n_k}) \to f(x)$. Now to show that $f$ is continuous, you can assume the contrary that $f$ is not continuous at $x$. Thus there is a fixed $\epsilon_0 >0$ and a sequence $x_n \to x$ so that 
$$\tag{1}d(f(x_n), f(x)) \ge \epsilon_0$$ 
for all $n\in \mathbb N$. But a subsequence of $x_{n_k}$ satisfies $f(x_{n_k}) \to f(x)$. Thus $(1)$ is not possible.

Comment: Is there a way that you could look at my edit?